# Ignore the word that has been replaced into specific words when comparing the folder / file

Tags: diff, file-comparison, winmerge, filecompare

I am using WinMerge to compare my Java source code because it is quite handy (comparing multiple folders and sub-folders, specifying the file extension you want to compare,...).

However, I want to ignore (return is identical or not hightlight) with the words I have specified. For example:

I want to ignore (not highlight as changed) `>> Macro.BW_16` if it is changed to `/16` or `>> 4` and other value will not ignore:

> Left line: `Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)((Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH >> Macro.BW_16) - 2);`
>
> Right line: `Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)(Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH / 16 - 2);`
>
> It will only highlight: Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)(`(`Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH >> Macro.BW_16`)` - 2); at the **Left** line.

Or:

> Left line: `Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)((Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH >> Macro.BW_16) - 2);`
>
> Right line: `Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)((Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH >> 4) - 2);`
>
> It will ignore (return as identical / without any highlighted).

Or:

> Left line: `Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)((Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH >> Macro.BW_16) - 2);`
>
> Right line: `Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)((Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH >> 16) - 2);`
>
> It will highlight: Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)((Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH `>> Macro.BW_16`) - 2); at the **Left** line.
>
> And: Macro.bytMaxHintWidth = (byte)((Macro.SCREEN_WIDTH `>> 16`) - 2); at the **Right** line.

I have tried using both the `Substitution Filters` and `PrediffLineFilter.sct` plugin, but neither of them are working.

[image: Substitution Filters]
[image: PrediffLineFilter.sct]

I reported [this issue](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/issues/1939) on their GitHub repository. There have been many answers / tests that were given but still could not solve this problem.

Therefore, I hope there will be another plugin / tool that can do the same and solve this problem.

I appreciate your answer.